# Best book for intro to probability theory?

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics, references

I have a weak math background and want to re-learn statistics from the ground up with theory (I'll be re-learning calculus and linear algebra to prep myself). That also means I'd like to learn things from the measure theory perspective. I had  two books recommended, Sheldon Ross' First Course in Probability and Henk Tijms Understanding Probability.

Anyone have a recommendation on which book is better? Are these understandable for someone self studying without a graduate degree? Or is there a better book out there altogether? I'd like a book that helps prep me for even more advanced topics as well

Comment: See [these](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Breferences%5D+%5Bprobability%5D+book) threads. Yours is likely a duplicate of one or more of them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Probability theory books for self-study](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15692/probability-theory-books-for-self-study)

Answer (score 2):

Mathematical Statistics with Applicationss (7th edition) by Wackerly, Mendenhall, and Scheaffer is super good. It is an undergraduate textbook that gives a detailed overview of probability theory along with many of its applications. Several examples of each topic with proofs are given to further understanding. There is even an appendix with information about R coding. I have found it super useful, and I hope you will to!